# I need some help in stata

Tags: stata, obs

I am not so good in STATA. I will appreciate your help here.
I want to know the number of observations in the dataset.
Secondly, I want to delete the last observations. Say I have 100, observations, I want to delete the last 10 observations.
Thirdly, I want to create a dummy which should take the form "Overweight, if BMI>25 and BMI<=30"
which codes can I use?

Comment: Please: Ask one question at a time. Choose a specific title for each question. Learn how to spell "Stata".  Here as a token is an answer to 1):  `display _N` or look at the output of `describe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of observations in a dataset you can use the command `count`. That displays the number of observations in the dataset. In many cases you can use `_N` to represent the number of observations programmatically in an expression.

You can use the command `drop` in combination with `in` to delete observation based on their sort order. `drop in -10/l` (notice that the last character is lower case L) means that all observations between the 10th obs from the last obs until the last (l as in last) observations will be dropped/deleted.

A dummy only takes the value `1`, `0` or missing. You can use *labels* in Stata to have `1` represent some string like "Overweight". Anyways, if you have a numeric variable called `BMI` then you can create your dummy like `generate overweight = (BMI > 25 & BMI <= 30) if !missing(BMI)`. The `if !missing(BMI)` part makes the `overweight` dummy missing if `BMI` is missing. Without this part it would have been `0` which is not the same as `0` means not overweight and missing means that we do not know if the person is overweight or not which is epistemologically very different.